# Checking if a message contains a string

Tags: java, string, contains

I have have a class that check id a phrase is contained in a message, I tried to do it with `Matcher` and `Pattern` and with `String.contains()`, but the results returned are odd.

Here is the class:

```
public class MotsClesFilter implements EmailFilter {

    final String NAME = "Filtrage par mots cles";
    /*private Pattern chaineSpam;
    private Matcher chaineCourriel;*/
    private int nbOccMotSpam;
    private byte confidenceLevel;
    @Override
    public String getFilterName() {
        return this.NAME;

    }

    @Override
    public byte checkSpam(MimeMessage message) {
        analyze(message);

        if(this.nbOccMotSpam==0)
            this.confidenceLevel = 1;
        else if (this.nbOccMotSpam>0 && this.nbOccMotSpam<2)
            this.confidenceLevel = CANT_SAY;
        else if (this.nbOccMotSpam>1 && this.nbOccMotSpam<3)
            this.confidenceLevel = 50;
        else if (this.nbOccMotSpam>3 && this.nbOccMotSpam<4)
            this.confidenceLevel = 65;
        else if (this.nbOccMotSpam>4 && this.nbOccMotSpam<5)
            this.confidenceLevel = 85;
        else this.confidenceLevel = 90;
        return (getConfidenceLevel());
    }


    public void analyze(MimeMessage message){
        try {
            List<String> listeChaines = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("SpamWords.txt"))));
            while(bis.ready()){
                String ligne = bis.readLine();
                listeChaines.add(ligne);
            }

            String mail = ((String.valueOf(message.getContent())));
            //System.out.println(mail);


            for (int j =0; j<listeChaines.size();j++){
                //System.out.println(listeChaines.get(j));
                Pattern chaineSpam = Pattern.compile(listeChaines.get(j),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher chaineCourriel = chaineSpam.matcher(mail);
                if (chaineCourriel.matches())
                    this.nbOccMotSpam++;

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public byte getConfidenceLevel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.confidenceLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

The results returned by `checkSpam` are always 1 if use matches and 90 if I use find, it also returns 90 when I use `mail.contains(listeChaines.get(j))`.

Comment: Both methods are valid, you would have to be careful with Pattern and Matcher as you may have non regex compatible characters in the `String`. `Contains` is a better choice. Maybe add some logging and use a debugger to see what's going on. Also the usual idiom for reading from a `BufferedReader` is `if((line = reader.readLine()) != null`.

Comment: I'd recommend using `switch` statements instead of those `if` statements. Besides, there are two `if` statements that will never be true.

Comment: which if are never true ? I tried contains but it works like find and it's not giving me the right results.

Comment: If the number is 3 or 4, the else clause will be executed. I doubt this is what you want. An integer can't be > 3 and < 4 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the message doesn't match any of the strings in the file, but that there are at least 5 strings in the file that can be found *inside* the message.

`matches()` checks if the *whole* string matches the pattern. Not if some substring matches it.

Comment: Yes but find and String.contains check if the wole pharase is inside the message isn'it ?

Comment: `contains()` checks that. `find()` checks if a substring matches the regex pattern. What's the problem? What are the inputs (message and listeChaines)? What are you expecting instead of what you get? As the comments indicate, you have bugs in your if statements. Is that the problem?

Comment: For listeChaines here it's a list thta ocntains usual spam expressions, message contains the content of an email.

Comment: That doesn't help. What is the contents of all those strings. Given these inputs, what output are you expecting, and what output do you get instead. From what you posted, 90 could be an expected output.

Comment: I have localised the problem, i think it's ok now, thanks everyone.